# openssl .so library version incompatible

Tags: c++, openssl, dkim, libssl, libcrypto

I wanted to upgrade the package OpenSSL to 1.1.1d from 1.0.0. However, there is another package OpenDKIM that depends on OpenSSL old version 1.0.0. So I made a symlink as below

```
ln -s libssl.so.1.1 libssl.so.1.0.0
ln -s libcrypto.so.1.1 libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

And following is the result of `ldd binary`

```
libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/zmta/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007fb6a52b4000)
libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/zmta/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007fb6a4df3000)
libopendkim.so.10 => /usr/lib/libopendkim.so.10 (0x00007fb6a4bd7000)
```

The compilation was okay in build machine centos7. But, when I try to run the binary in Ubuntu-18.04, the following error occurred.

> libcrypto.so.10: version `libcrypto.so.10' not found (libopendkim.so.10). No file or directory named libcrypto.so.10

So I created a symlink file libcrypto.so.10 pointing to libcrypto.so.1.1, but the following error occurred.

> libcrypto.so.10: version `libcrypto.so.10' not found (libopendkim.so.10)

I could not get through this error. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try using `ldd` or `readelf` to examine the lib for its dependencies. You may have to upgrade several other libraries [that are not part of what you already downloaded] to compatible versions. That's why binary package managers (e.g. `yum`, `dnf`, `apt`) will force upgrade of dependent packages. You may also need to run `ldconfig` and, possibly, add some entries to its config.

Comment: That is a binary I have created. openssl needed by binary is in the latest version 1.1. opendkim depends on openssl 1.0 does not support latest version 1.1. So, I did the above workaround. Sometimes when I remove libcrypto.so.10 it works, but does not work if I include the file.

Comment: So, pull the source for `opendkim` and rebuild it

Comment: BTW, I think you'll need to post more details about the exact steps you did to get to where you are. And, your question is more about rebuilding a package than a problem with a program you wrote. You might get a better answer on superuser or serverfault sister sites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenSSL package can be a dependency for multiple other dependency packages that you are using for your application.

If you are trying to bundle the dependencies along with your application, then you will have to manually take care of the dependencies.

If you are trying to upgrade OpenSSL, you will have to look if other dependencies like OpenDKIM supports the upgraded version of OpenSSL.

If other dependencies(OpenDKIM) support the upgraded version of OpenSSL, you will have to recompile those dependencies(OpenDKIM) against the new version of OpenSSL.

In the above case, just adding symlink libssl.so.1.1 that points to an older version library libssl.so.1.0.0 will not work.

**Note:** While recompiling other dependencies(OpenDKIM) for your application, they are not compiled against an older version. Even when your OpenSSL is updated to the required new version, there are older libraries that still exist for compatibility.

While compiling other dependencies, if they take the older version library and header files of OpenSSL in the system, then runtime issues in version mismatch will occur.